# Input File field to Input Text field

Tags: javascript, file, input, field, input-field

I don't even know if this is possible or not but is there a method you can take the value of the selected file in a input **file** field to a input **text** field?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hook on the `change` event of the file field.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" onchange="this.form.filename.value = this.value">
    <input type="text" name="filename">
</form>
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VaeAN/). Note that IE6/7 incorrectly gives the full path while other browsers correctly gives only the filename.

Comment: MSIE should give only the filename as well since IE 8.

Comment: @Pekka: I peeked in your profile. Does that Amazon.com Wishlist have effect? Funny idea :)

Comment: nope, not yet! I really *would* like to see something arrive from that list one day  :)

Comment: What about when input file is "multiple"? How to get the value for all the files selected?

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by creating a new text input element and populating it with the `.value` property of the file input.

Note, however, that all modern browsers store *only the file name* in the `value` property for security reasons. You will not be able to get the full path of the selected file.

Sources: [MSDN on IE8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it without first storing the file on your own server.

The file input control does *not* contain the file's data.  Your browser provides it to you as a placeholder until you submit the file data via a POST form submission.

If you're after the file's path, you also cannot do that (in modern browsers, as Pekka says).  The browser does not give that information to client-side scripts.  It may provide the filename, however.

Comment: I think he is looking to only copy the file path, not its data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the value can be read, though not written. So what he's interested in is doable. See BalusC's answer.